# unable to get location in webview

Tags: geolocation, android-webview, webviewclient

Hi i am not getting location in my java script function opened in a android web view same code get location when it is opened in android browser

```
_webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        _webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        _webview.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        _webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //  _webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        _webview.setWebViewClient(new GeoWebViewClient());
        _webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        _webview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        // _webview.setWebChromeClient(new GeoWebChromeClient());

        Log.i("onPageStarted", "Processing webview url click..."+this.getApplicationContext().getDir("database",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getPath());
        _webview.getSettings().setGeolocationDatabasePath( "/data/data/" +this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "/app_database/");
        _webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
                callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
            }
        });
        _webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/hello.html");
```

and these are the permissions i have given in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
```